# print multiple words separated by space

Tags: text-processing, awk, printf

I have a text file and the data inside has format like (name age country):

```
michael jordans 25 US
adam smith 30 UK
chris wood ABC 22 Aus
```

if I use command: `cat text.txt | awk {'print $1'}` --> it will print:

```
michael
adam
chris
```

but I want to print the full name:

```
michael jordans
adam smith
chris wood ABC
```

Which command should I use ?

We can change the format data like:

```
michael jordans|25|US
adam smith|30|UK
chris wood ABC|22|Aus
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\).*/\1/' text.tex
```

This assumes that the name does not contain a numeric character and the field just after the name starts with a number.

When you separate the fields by `|`, it can be done by

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*\).*/\1/' text.tex
```

or if you like awk, you can do

```
awk -F\| '{print $1}' text.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the file to have proper field separators, like `|`, the solution is trivial:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1}' input_file
```

If you use blanks, which also occur within the intended fields, instead of proper field separators, then you can do something like this:

```
 awk '{ a = $1; for (i=2; i <= NF-2; i++) a = a " " $i; print a; }' input_file
```